# Accessing tomcat management page from Spring tool set 4

Tags: spring-boot, apache-camel, spring-tool-suite, tomcat9

I have developed a Camel Rout using Spring. I used the STS4 IDE to develop the same.

When I started the application using Run As-> Spring Boot App, the application starts and also I can see from the logs that the route is started.
My route is a basic app, the exposes a rest endpoint and logs a Hello World

```
@Override
public void configure() throws Exception {
    restConfiguration()
      .enableCORS(true)
      .apiContextPath("/api-doc")
        .apiProperty("api.title", "Test REST API")
        .apiProperty("api.version", "v1")
        .apiContextRouteId("doc-api")
      .component("servlet")
      .bindingMode(RestBindingMode.json);

    rest("/api/")
      .id("api-route")
      .consumes("application/json")
      .get("/test")
        .to("direct:log");

    from("direct:log")
        .id("log")
        .log(LoggingLevel.INFO,"Test successful");
}
```

What I am expecting is that if I do localhost:8080/api/test, i will see some logs "Test Susccessful" in the Tomcat logs. I am using tomcat 9, Instead what I get WhiteLable error. I thought there is an issue with my code so I tried localhost:8080 and i was expecting the Tomcat Management server to open. Even that is not working.

I am not starting Tomcat separately. What I am doing is Run As-> Spring Boot App and I guess it is calling the embedded tomcat.

Comment: Check your logs, the base url of Camel servlet is logged there. It is probably mapped to `/camel/**`, if you kept default values, so try with `http://localhost:8080/camel/api/test`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Credit for this answer goes to @Bedla. I had to add camel in the URL path http://localhost:8080/camel/api/test